# Slopes and intercepts of categorical variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset of 27 years of bird ages and wing measurements, and in my dataset my variables are Year, Age, and Wing. I've plotted the measurements by year using facet_wrap in ggplot2, but I want to have the slope and intercept of each year's growth curve and to see if there's a significant difference between the years. My dataset is called ATPU and this is the closest I've gotten to what I want so far using dplyr. Is there an easier way to do this?

```
ATPU$Year <- as.factor((ATPU$Year))

ATPU %>%
  group_by(Year)

fitted_models=ATPU %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  do(model=lm(Wing~Age, data=ATPU))
fitted_models$model
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could get your slopes and intercepts as a tidy dataframe using `dplyr::nest_by` and `broom::tidy`.

Using the `gapminder` dataset as example data:

```r
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
library(gapminder)

fitted_models <- gapminder %>%
  nest_by(year) %>%
  mutate(model = list(lm(lifeExp ~ gdpPercap, data = data)))

summarise(fitted_models, broom::tidy(model))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'year'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 24 × 6
#> # Groups:   year [12]
#>     year term         estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>    <int> <chr>           <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1  1952 (Intercept) 47.7      1.07          44.8  7.79e-85
#>  2  1952 gdpPercap    0.000365 0.000106       3.42 8.08e- 4
#>  3  1957 (Intercept) 49.9      1.07          46.6  4.22e-87
#>  4  1957 gdpPercap    0.000376 0.0000998      3.77 2.38e- 4
#>  5  1962 (Intercept) 51.1      1.07          47.6  2.28e-88
#>  6  1962 gdpPercap    0.000535 0.000109       4.91 2.51e- 6
#>  7  1967 (Intercept) 51.9      1.05          49.5  1.20e-90
#>  8  1967 gdpPercap    0.000695 0.000107       6.48 1.48e- 9
#>  9  1972 (Intercept) 54.3      1.01          53.7  2.47e-95
#> 10  1972 gdpPercap    0.000493 0.0000805      6.12 8.66e- 9
#> # … with 14 more rows
```